# Extracting part of a string using regex

Tags: regex

I am trying to extract part of a strings below

I tried (.*)(?:table)?,it fails in the last case. How to make the expression capture entire string in the absence of the text "table"

1. Text: "diningtable"  Expected Match: dining
2. Text: "cookingtable" Match: cooking
3. Text: "cooking" Match:cooking
4. Text: "table" Match:""

Comment: Try [`^((?:(?!table).)+)(?:table)?$`](https://regex101.com/r/bM8nZ8/1)

Comment: Wow..would you mind explaining that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use regex, you can use this one:

```
(^.*)(?=table)|(?!.*table.*)(^.+)
```

See demo here: [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/fR5rX6/3)

The idea is: match everything from the beginning of the line `^` until the word `table` or if you don't find table in the string, match at least one symbol. (to avoid matching empty lines). Thus, when it finds the word table, it will return an empty string (because it matches from the beginning of the line till the word table).

Answer (score 2):

Rather than try to match everything but `table`, you should do a replacement operation that removes the text `table`.

Depending on the language, this might not even need regex. For example, in Java you could use:

```
String output = input.replace("table", "");
```

Comment: Good point! I will take the suggestion :) But I was trying to learn regex and this looked like a simple enough problem, but apparently not.

Answer (score 1):

The [`(.*)(?:table)?`](https://regex101.com/r/cV0hJ0/1) fails with `table` (matches it) as the first group `(.*)` is a *greedy dot* matching pattern that grabs the whole string into Group 1. The regex engine backtracks and looks for `table` in the optional non-capturing group, and matches an empty string at the end of the string.

[image]

The **regex** trick is to match any text that does not start with `table` *before* the optional group:

```
^((?:(?!table).)+)(?:table)?$
```

See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bM8nZ8/1)

Now, Group 1 - `((?:(?!table).)+)` - contains a [**tempered greedy token**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37343088/3832970) `(?:(?!table).)+` that matches 1 or more chars other than a newline that do not start a `table` sequence. Thus, the first group will never match `table`.

The anchors make the regex match the whole line.

**NOTE**: Non-regex solutions might turn out more efficient though, as a tempered greedy token is rather resource consuming.

**NOTE2**: Unrolling the tempered greedy token usually enhances performance n times:

```
^([^t]*(?:t(?!able)[^t]*)*)(?:table)?$
```

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/bM8nZ8/2)

But usually it looks "cryptic", "unreadable", and "unmaintainable".

Comment: So, only use this solution **if** you cannot use a "normal" programming language. An unrolled version is much faster, but is really hard to maintain since few people can understand a good, efficient regex pattern.

Comment: Is there a way to extract everything except the last "table", like "tablettable", to return tablet?

Comment: Well, that is of course possible with *matching* - [`^((?:(?!table$).)+)(?:table)?$`](https://regex101.com/r/oY0nI0/1). But you'd better just check if the string ends with `table`, and remove it. Or with regex.replace - `table$`.

Comment: Yep, I will do that. It looks a bit odd though that I have to exclude "table" from the first group to achieve this. All I want is everything except the last optional "table". Thank you though..makes me feel better that it indeed was a difficult problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Despite other great answers, you could also use alternation:

```
^(?|(.*)table$|(.*))$
```

This makes use of a branch reset, so your desired content is always stored in group 1. If your language/tool of choice doesn't support it, you would have to check which of groups 1 and 2 contains the string.

See [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/oR3iW4/1)